# How to write the data from Mysql into a file using jdbc code and file writer?

Tags: jdbc

```
String selectTableSQL = "select JobID, MetadataJson from raasjobs join metadata using (JobID) where JobCreatedDate > '2014-07-01';";
    File file = new File("/users/t_shetd/file.txt");
    try {
        dbConnection = getDBConnection();
        statement = dbConnection.createStatement();

        System.out.println(selectTableSQL);

        // execute select SQL stetement
        ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery(selectTableSQL);
        if (!file.exists()) {
            file.createNewFile();
        }

        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
        while (rs.next()) {

        String JobID = rs.getString("JobID");
        String Metadata = rs.getString("MetadataJson");
        bw.write(selectTableSQL);
        bw.close();
        System.out.println("Done");
```

**// Now i am only getting the output done**

Comment: Try writing jobid or metadata, as is you're writing your query string.

Comment: I tried that too, than only jobid or metadatajson are printed in to the file created rather than data of the column jobid or metadatajson

Comment: Don't put those variable names in quotes.

Comment: Hi i tried that too. With and without quotes

Comment: this is my output, instead of being stored in a text file:
Done Job ID : 8fd14735-b195-4c27-b99c-5bf1a2d35834
Metadata : {"Slaves":"1","kdt build Box Gen":"0.00323034008","Job Render":"19.1420002","Adaptation

Comment: What are you expecting and how does it differ from what you posted?

Comment: this query is to display 1000 of jobs , i want to store them in a text file, but in that text file i only get JOBID , this word as output insetad of what is stored in a field name JobID that is 1000 of job ids

Comment: it is only printing the whole details of one jobid instead of all jobs

Comment: Your while loop, where is the closing brace?

Comment: there is brace, i just forgot to mention her, but there is beace in my code else it would not have run only, the thing is i want 1000 jobid in a text file but i only get one jobid and details in the text file instead of 1000. There is no brace error, i just forgot to show it here

Comment: it closes after System.out.println("Done");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question, then this

```
while (rs.next()) {
  String JobID = rs.getString("JobID");
  String Metadata = rs.getString("MetadataJson");
  bw.write(selectTableSQL);
  bw.close();
  System.out.println("Done");
}
```

Should be something like (following Java capitalization conventions),

```
while (rs.next()) {
  String jobId = rs.getString("JobID");
  String metaData = rs.getString("MetadataJson");
  bw.write(String.format("Job ID: %s, MetaData: %s", jobId, metaData));
}
bw.close(); // <-- finish writing first!
System.out.println("Done");
```

In your version, you close the output after printing the first line from the ResultSet. After that, nothing else will write (because the File is closed).